# What does the word "mortarboard" mean, as it relates to an SE badge?

Tags: discussion, etymology

I like the creative names on SE badges, but a couple of them went over my head.  What is "[mortarboard](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/25/mortarboard)"?

Comment: @kzh: I had considered that, but my question has more to do with how the word "mortarboard" relates to the badge than the badge itself.  That is an English question.  The name of the badge is more in English territory, and the workings of the badge, what it does, etc, is more into meta territory.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: @kzh: Thanks for conceding; I wasn't going to fight about it!

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I did say "where did the name come from".

Comment: Yes, but the question title is about a badge, while the question is about the word _mortarboard_. In other words, you are asking "what does _mortarboard_, used to name a badge in SE sites, mean?"

Comment: For the record, I think this should have stayed on the main site. The question asks, "What is a mortarboard?" and uses the badge as an example of use. This, as far as I know, has nothing to do with Meta.

Comment: @MrHen The question, as originally stated, had an overbearing focus on SE. Assume that the question had had such a focus on another site—in that case, I would have had to have closed it as "too localized" or "off topic". If the question had merely asked what a mortarboard was in more general terms, it would be "general reference". And I couldn't just leave it be because it was flagged, so I did my best to rescue the question. (By the way, this follows from a general policy at MSO).

Comment: @waiwai: Fair enough. I guess I more think it _doesn't_ belong here than I think it belonged on the main site. As in, I am not sure it belongs anywhere but I get the feeling it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @waiwai, @MrHen: You're both right.  I could have looked it up and applied the metaphor, to an extent, myself.  The answer here is helpful, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mortarboard is the name of the cap worn by someone graduating (e.g., from high school or college).

From [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mortarboard) (definition 2), a mortarboard is:

> An academic cap topped by a flat square.

Presumably it was chosen for the particular badge of, "Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day" to symbolize a degree of academic merit.

Comment: Oh, so it's a type of graduation.  Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly; it's less about "graduation" and more about recognizing academic merit. It takes some effort to hit the reputation cap on most SE sites; you're either answering a lot of questions or posting a few really good answers which garner a lot of upvotes in one day. The mortarboard cap worn in academic ceremonies is a similar symbol of academic achievement, so the term was used for the badge.

Comment: In the UK, where we do not have the concept of "graduating" at the high school level (only at University), the mortarboard is much more strongly associated with schoolteachers than students. Although teachers have not worn them in my time (55 years), they still do so in the pages of comics like "The Beano" (http://www.beano.com/characters/bash-street-kids). So to me, "mortarboard" means "teacher", not "excellent student"

Comment: @Colin, a mortarboard means a *graduating* student, not an *excellent* one. (If statistics are to be believed, most graduates these days are not, in fact, excellent students.) But the image is still academics, which is what the badge name is trying to convey. I think.

Comment: @Martha, or a _graduated_ student, which is why professors _also_ often wear mortarboards to graduating ceremonies (at least when they sit up on stage). Not that this changes anything, though. (A _graduating_ student wears her tassel on the right, and a _graduated_ student wears her tassel on the left.)

Comment: Excellent example of a metaphor that is totally insensitive to cultural diversity.

Comment: @CesarGon: I don't know how this is any more or less insensitive than _most_ metaphors. I'm hard-pressed to come up with any metaphor that translates well across all cultures.

Comment: @Ben Hocking: http://www.amazon.com/Metaphors-We-Live-George-Lakoff/dp/0226468011

Comment: @CesarGon: It sounds interesting, but can you give me an example of a metaphor that is culturally sensitive in a way that this mortarboard metaphor is not? I'm not disbelieving that you can think of one, but I can't think of one, at least not right now.

Comment: @Ben Hocking: You don't need to be explicitly culturally-senstive; you just need to be culturally-neutral, and "mortarboard" is not. Some examples: we devour a book of raw facts, try to digest them, stew over them, let them simmer, regurgitate them in discussions, cook up explanations, hoping they do not seem half-baked. We establish a foundation for our theories, support them with strong arguments, buttressing them with facts, hoping they will stand.

Comment: @CesarGon - I find all your cooking metaphors deeply offensive to raw food vegans

Comment: @Martin Beckett: Well, yeah, and I find the fact that you tell me this on a digital medium deeply offensive to luddites and the anti-technology movement. Let's keep it sane, please.

Answer (score 5):

One of these:

[image]

The shape comes from the board used to hold mortar in bricklaying or pastering

[image]

It's used as a hat at university graduation to remind you how much more you would have made if you had a trade.

Comment: lol. I taste a hint of sour grapes here...

Comment: @T.E.D ironically plastering is the one skill I haven't picked up in a career as an experimental physicist. Plumbing, shop class, glass blowing, scaffolding, concrete mixing etc all part of big science!